Can't check multiple checkboxes when using acf in woocommerce product's page
I have created a csv file for importing products in woocommerce. I've created some custom fields using ACF. In 2 of those ACF fields I've selected the checkbox as type because the product can have multiple values for that field. As other default columns I've provided the values comma separately but it doesn't work if I provide multiple values using comma. It only works if I provide one value to be selected.

As you can see in the image I've provided comma separated values to be selected in the checkboxes. It doesn't work. But when I remove other values like 2300K, 3500K and just keeps the 1900K it works. I've searched too much on StackOverflow. Asked ChatGPT and Gemini but no results. Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
